# Why am I getting a syntax error in MySQL when I used Group By?

Tags: mysql, sql

Why am I getting an error on the last line?

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    datawarehouse.shipments
WHERE
    ControlBranch = 'SFO'
        AND ShipmentCreateDateUTC >= '2020-03-01'

ORDER BY id DESC
GROUP BY ShipmentNumber;
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is order by id Desc, Group by ShipmentNumber, and then pull all the fields.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your query doesn't make much sense in its current form; you cannot use 'SELECT *' in combination with 'GROUP BY' in a sensible way (earlier versions of MySQL allowed this and returned random data for this kind of queries). What column(s) do you want to aggregate (using SUM, MIN, MAX, ...), and what column(s) define your groups?

Comment: Because `group by` comes before `order by`

Comment: Also, for `select *` you can't group by a single column

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all the query won't work because you are grouping something, and then showing everything with an * syntax. You need to show the column that you are grouping and then use aggregating functions with the rest (SUM, COUNT, AVG, etc) so it shows the value grouped. 
After that, you need to check the instruction order that SQL Server uses. The Order by goes always at the end of the instructions. So, the correct order of your query is like this:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) -- The count is an example
FROM datawarehouse.shipments
WHERE
    ControlBranch = 'SFO'
    AND ShipmentCreateDateUTC >= '2020-03-01'
GROUP BY ShipmentNumber
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Also, even if it's not relevant, you can have a better understanding of how the engine works behind the curtain (the order of execution) checking this link:
https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/06/sql-server-logical-query-processing-phases-order-of-statement-execution/

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish is order by id Desc, Group by ShipmentNumber, and then pull all the fields.